# How to create a Win 8 tablet application in c#

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, tablet, tablet-pc

Is it possible to create a win8(normal) application for tablet using C# (VS2010).

If possible, can any one show me an example how to create a simple application to turn on Win 8 tablet's Bluetooth.

Please help. I have no experience in win8 application development.

Answer (score 1):

To create the new Windows store apps you need Visual Studio 2012. You can still use 2010 to create normal Desktop applications (WinForms, WPF).

Comment: only Desktop applications. If you want the new store apps you need the 2012 Express Edition: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8